# How to change position of rigged bones using python in pose mode?

Tags: python, rigging, bones, error, pose-mode

I am new to Blender and I have been trying to execute this following code which is supposed to change the position of currently selected Pose bone (rigged) in pose mode  :

```py
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')

armature = "basicRig"
tail = bpy.data.objects[armature].location + bpy.context.active_pose_bone.tail
head = bpy.data.objects[armature].location + bpy.context.active_pose_bone.head
name = bpy.context.active_pose_bone.name
print(name)
print(head)
print(tail) 
bpy.context.active_pose_bone.translate(Vector((10, 10, 10)))
```

But its showing this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/snap/blender/20/2.79/scripts/modules/bpy_types.py", line 167, in translate
    self.head += vec
AttributeError: bpy_struct: attribute "head" from "PoseBone" is read-only
```

Can someone help me in finding out a way to move or transform the location of pose bones using python? Or is it even possible to change position of any pose bone(s) in pose mode?

PS: I have already gone through other articles and forums but haven't been able to find some properly working solution.